# need to run mail utility in linux OS

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, storage

I need small help from you guys..I 'm not that confident in Linux commands.So, anybody who can guide be 'll be very much appreciated.

I want my  celerra (Control station  which is Linux OS based) to generate a utilization report and send a mail to our storage team ID.

This is the command :

```
>##nas_pool -size -a

>id           = 3

>name         = clar_r5_performance

>used_mb      = 23476466

>avail_mb     = 6568607

>total_mb     = 30045073

>potential_mb = 0
```

I want this report to be delivered to my ID at 9AM CST. Can somebody how need to set up this.Pointers are welcome.
Please help me with the steps...thanks you all!

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your crontab:

```
0 9 * * * nas_pool -size -a | mail -s report user@example.com
```

...of course this is predicated on the fact that you have a working MTA of some sort running on your server, but that's another question. :)

Comment: You can test it from the command line by running it without the leading "0 9 * * *" and make sure the mail comes through.  If it doesn't, look at the logs in /var/log/maillog or /var/log/mail.log

Comment: I tried with -"nas_pool -size -a | mail -s report user@example.com"   still no mail.Is it that i need to add celerra IP to exchange server ?   even mail -v user@example.com is working still no mails..please help on how to troubleshoot this..

Comment: focus on sending a mail, forget the NAS part for now. Your exchange server probably refuse your mail because your use doesn't exist (root) in it's domain database. I think that you must send the mail as yourself, or create a service user in exchange and use this email as the sender. Use mutt to send your mail. http://wiki.mutt.org/?MuttFaq/Header check this page and make sure you send your mail with an address known by your mail platform.

Answer (score 1):

Simply edit your crontab.

I noticed you stated you were not sure how to get around in linux much... so this may help

From the command line run this command:

## crontab -e

Copy and paste ErikA's excellent response adjusting the email address of course

```
0 9 * * * nas_pool -size -a | mail -s report user@example.com
```

and then save

most of the time you will be in a VI or vim based editior... 
simple press the escape key and then type wq (for write/ quit)

and voila - this should be in place

Blessings,

Comment: Thank you all for the help!(Erika, glenn,sean)..I tried                        "nas_pool -size clar_r5_performance | mail -s report MYID@example.com" after crontab -e ,it asked for press enter or type command. I copied and pasted the commenad above and the after few lines it asked for ~insert .I pressed the Insert tab and then "Q"..It said recording and then stopped nothing happened. Was it the right process ? I still didn't get mail or anything...please help

Comment: [root@usdadcgwspul00 nasadmin]# /var/log/maillog
bash: /var/log/maillog: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste ErikA's excellent response adjusting the email address of course

0 9 * * * nas_pool -size -a | mail -s report user@example.com

along with saving the file opened in vim or vi editor

you have to start the cron job bye typing this command

```
# service crond restart
```

Comment: along with that start the sendmail service bye command 
   # service sendmail restart